# shuffle error:exceeded max_failed_unique_matche : bailing out

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop and i am trying to execute the wordcount example. I have a cluster of 4 nodes made by virtual machines on my computer. Every time the job completes the map task but the reduce task at time about 16% shows this error:

Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.

12/05/24 04:43:12 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputmachine3-VirtualBox

It looks like the slaves are unable to retrieve data from other slaves. On some links I found that it can come due to inconsistency in /etc/hosts file. But I have cross-checked them, and they are all consistent. Can anyone help me out

Comment: Can you post the logs from one of your reduce task attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a firewall preventing communications between the cluster nodes on the common hadoop ports (50060 for the task tracker in this case). Test by doing a curl from one node to another on port 50060 and check you get an http response code:

```
curl -I http://node1:50060/
```

Be sure to replace 'node1' in the above with each of the values in the `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves` file

*EDIT* So it turns out this is most probably a DNS problem, here's what you should try:

- Examine the `${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/slaves` file - each entry in here needs to be in the /etc/hosts file for each node in your cluster, or you must have them in your networks DNS server
- Once you've asserted the hosts file *ON EVERY NODE* in your cluster (or configured your DNS server), log into each node and check that you can ping the other cluster nodes by the names in the slaves file. Finally assert you can curl the tasktracker (port 50060) from each node to the other nodes (again using the machine names in the slaves file)
- Restart your mapreduce services, just to be safe

Comment: I have created the network by hosting a virtual host only network to communicate between nodes. I don't think there is any firewall

Comment: the nodes are listening to the port 50060

Comment: ok so does curl'ing from one node to another on port 50060 work?

Comment: well its returning:
curl:couldn't connect to host

Comment: and does the tasktracker logs for the node you're trying to connect to show that it is running on port 50060. Can you ping from one host to another?

Comment: the tasktracker logs for the slave node doen't show anything about port 50060. however i am able to ping from one node to another.

Comment: actually i am using a virtual host only network to communicate between virtual machines.Can that create some problem?

Comment: if the task trackers are listening on 50060 on each of the cluster nodes and you can't curl from one node to another on port 50060 but you can ping from one to another, then you have a firewall problem.

Comment: and what does `sudo iptables --list --verbose` return

Comment: it is returning : _CHAIN INPUT(policy ACCEPT)_ similarly for _CHAIN FORWARD_ and _CHAIN OUTPUT_. however it is not returning any ip

Comment: actually curl is also working getting an OK http response code ....i was doing a silly mistake at time of using curl......can you please figure out the problem?? its troubling very much

Comment: So doing a `curl -I http://outputmachine3-VirtualBox:50060/` from outputmachine1 or 2 gets a response?

Comment: it says couldn't resove host 'outputmachine3-VirtualBox"

Comment: So a closing comment - if your error log in the reducer says it encountered an error reading the map output from outputmachine3-VirtualBox, and you get cannot resolve host, then you have DNS issues. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: i appreciate your help but i have been struck in this problem for 3 days. Please do reply

Comment: Are you still stuck? If so you'll need to post your master and slaves file, along with the /etc/hosts file from each and every node in your cluster (are are you using DNS?)

Answer (score 1):

Check hostname in each node by typing $hostname in terminal. Ensure that you get the same name of your machine (master in master node and slave in slave node). If not, change /etc/hostname with your node name (master/slave). Then restart the system. It will works.

[SIMPLE Groups](http://simplegec.blogspot.in)

Comment: Thanks ! I owe you a beer ;).. i was stuck hard at it for long... .