# Too many fetch failures on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I am a Hadoop/Pig beginner.

I am trying to build a hadoop clsuter. With one data node and Master node also acting as data node.
I have followed the instructions given in : http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

When I try to run the sample hadoop examples. I am getting "Too many fetch failures".

I have all the names of the master and the host configured in /etc/hosts of both the master and the slave.
I have also changed the somaxconn value to 1024.

What am I missing here? Please help.

Comment: For some reason the reducer is not able to fetch files from HDFS. Check if this helps - http://zepvn.com/blog/?p=90.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. Do you see any configuration issue? I have done everything as mentioned in the blog. Or is it some networking issue?

Comment: Looks more of a networking issue.

Comment: Can you post some logs from one of your reducer task attempts? Also confrm that you can curl/wget the tasktracker http port from one node to the other - this could be a firewall issue between your two nodes

Comment: Also see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729543/shuffle-errorexceeded-max-failed-unique-matche-bailing-out

Comment: I am getting some errors in the Jobtracker too. Here is the error message.
2012-06-29 10:30:36,343 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: 2012-06-29 10:30:36,344 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null 
2012-06-29 10:30:36,344 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: could not get block locations. Source file "/var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info" - Aborting... 2012-06-29 10:30:36,344 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Writing to file hdfs://master:9000/var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info failed!
2012-06-29 10:30:36,344 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: FileSystem is not ready yet!

Comment: Task Tracker on Master works fine. However on the slave I am getting this:
2012-06-29 10:36:25,303 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: getMapOutput(attempt_201206291030_0001_m_000000_0,0) failed :
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find taskTracker/airavat/jobcache/job_201206291030_0001/attempt_201206291030_0001_m_000000_0/output/file.out.index in any of the configured local directories
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:429)

Comment: 2012-06-29 10:36:25,303 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown child with bad map output: attempt_201206291030_0001_m_000000_0. Ignored.

Comment: And curl -I http:slave:50060/ is working fine from both the master and th eslave

Comment: Also, I checked the logs after copying the file to hdfs. The logs have no errors and data gets distributed to all data nodes.

Comment: It works well with only one namenode and one datanode. When I add one more data node it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Check HDFS bug database for the status of this bug and its fix.
Work around is to use / replace jetty.jar with latest or higher version > 1.26
Other option is to increase fetch attempts, in the mapred-site.xml

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report, perhaps?

Comment: it is good to provide links to resources you're mentioning in your answer.